# How Can I position the text over the image

Tags: html, css

I can't get the text box at the bottom to appear over the image without messing up the navigation bar
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfCDY.jpg
I've tried all sorts of things and the text either just doesn't move the way I expect or messes up my navbar as I said
I'd be extremely happy if someone could help as I need to finish this in a few days for school.

```
here's my css code
```

```
body{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}
header{
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
footer{
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: : -5px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.bgimage{
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  width: 1920px;
}
.container{

}
.imgtext{
  border-style: solid;
  color: white;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;




}
.YeStage{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 700px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.menu {
  margin-top: : -20px;
  ma
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #3b1113;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0
  border:0;
}
.Logo {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0px
  margin-bottom: 0px
  width: 440px;
  height: 50px;
}

.menu  a {
  float: left;
  color: #FFFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 36px 38px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;



}


.menu  a:hover {
  background-color: #f5bd0e;
  color: black;
}


.menu  a.active {
  background-color: #f5bd0e;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: can you supply the html as well so we can investigate what might be causing the issue? Thanks and welcome to SO